# In a freezer, what stops the suction line from freezing over?

Tags: air-conditioning

After the gas has expanded through the evaporator coils, what would stop the pipes circled in this image to not freeze over? Could it be that the size of the evaporator coil is the perfect size to use up all of the energy of the expanding gas?
[image: Freezer Diagram]

Comment: Sometimes the suction lines will have frost. Most of the energy is released when the liquid expands at the metering device into a gas and enters the evaporator where the cold is transferred. With a properly designed, charged and operating system when the gas exits the evaporator the temperature is usually above freezing.

Comment: The refrigerant is designed to have a very low freeze point. Remember also that the expanded gas has just absorbed energy from the airflow, so the temperature of the gas upon exiting the exchanger is (should be) considerably higher than upon initial expansion.